# Left Join COUNT on tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, left-join

I have 2 tables:

```
puid | personid | ptitle
----------------------------
1    | 200      | richard
2    | 201      | swiss

suid | personidref | stitle
----------------------------
1    | 200         | alf
2    | 201         | lando
3    | 200         | willis
4    | 201         | luke
5    | 201         | kojak
6    | 200         | r2-d2
7    | 201         | jabba
```

I am trying to left join with a count of table two. I have tried to figure out to use `generate_series` or sub selects but I cant noodle the syntax.

In english: show me each unique person in table one with a count of each entry in table two.

example output:

```
puid | personid | ptitle  | count
---------------------------------
1    | 200      | richard | 3
2    | 201      | swiss   | 4
```

Is this is simple subquery, is `generate_series` the right tool for the job?

Comment: `generate_series()` has no role to play here. It's a simple matter of `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: ill go back and read the docs for `generate_series` and try to apply the use case correctly, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from
    t1
    left join
    (
        select personidref, count(*) total
        from t2
        group by personidref
    ) s using(personidref)
order by puid
```

Notice that doing the aggregation before joining probably has a performance gain over doing it after.

Comment: so this is a newb question here... so the subquery always fires first then right? hence the product can be used in the primary query. Ill play around with various versions of this to get comfortable with it. Thanks!

Comment: @robert Since it is joining to a computed table it obviously has to compute it first.